# Pycharm - external css file stopped working after Pycharm re-activation

Tags: css, pycharm, external

I have been scratching my head for 5 hours.

I'm building a website and up until yesterday all my external css files worked correctly.

Today when starting Pycharm I got a message that I needed to 'activate' it. I did, and went to my Project directory and continue to work but noticed that the .css file is not responding to any changes that I made. In fact it's literally freezed to where it was yesterday. Even when erasing everything in that .css file, it renders the same exact style.

Anyone have any similar experiences? I don't know what happened or what to do.

For context I'm gonna put my layout file below:

`layout.html`:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/main.js') }}">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='css/main.css') }}" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>

    {% block content %}{% endblock %}

</body>
</html>
```

Project directory: C:\Users\PATTY\Desktop\Project_Website\Scrapy\Test_Scrapy

```
Test_Scrapy>
    Test_Scrapy(other non-related dir)
static>
    css>
        main.css
    js>
        main.js
templates>
    layout.html
    main.html
    search.html
my_website.py
```

Updated:

```
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger pin code: 230-950-485
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017 17:53:09] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017 17:53:10] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017 17:53:10] "GET /static/js/main.js HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017 17:53:10] "GET /static/css/main.css HTTP/1.1" 304 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017 17:53:14] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 -
127.0.0.1 - - [09/Mar/2017 17:54:04] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
```

Comment: Do you use css preprocessor?

Comment: Is url_for getting a main.css from some other package/location? Try something a little more unique than "main.css" as your file name.

Comment: I updated the OP with the errors that I got.